# Laravel Multiple relationships data fetch

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database, relationship

Good day. I have this relationship problem in laravel
I have three models

1. User
2. State
3. School

I have established the following relationships between them

a. School - User (A user can enroll in many schools)

**In User Model**

```
public function schools(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\School', 'school_user', 'user_id', 'school_id');
}
```

b. A school can have many users

**In School Model**

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'school_user', 'school_id', 'user_id');
}
```

c. A school belongs to a state (i.e c an be found in a state)

**In School Model**

```
public function states(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\State');
}
```

d. A state has many schools

**In State Model**

```
public function schools(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\School');
}
```

Now, I know how to query models with immediate relationship. For example, I can get the users associated with a school and vice-versa. I can also get the schools in a state.

**My Question**
How do I get all users associated with schools in a given state (using a query)? Assuming all we have is just the name of a state.

And probably get all schools the users are associated with and the date(time) in which there were associated with the schools?

This is what I have done. The second query is not giving me an answer

```
public function details(){
        
        //Get all schools associated with a state 
        $schools = State::with('schools')->where('id',1)->first();
        
         foreach($schools->schools as $data){
          //Get all users associated with the schools
          $users = School::with('users')->where('id',$data->id);
          dd($users);  
        }    
    }
```

Apart from the fact that this approach is not probably right, I am not getting any answer. Is there a query or method that can solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `whereHas` you can get all users that belong to schools with the given `state_id`.

```
$state = State::find(1);

$users = User::whereHas('schools', function ($query) use ($state) {
    $query->where('state_id', $state->id);
})->get();
```

[Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

> If you need even more power, you may use the `whereHas` and `orWhereHas`
> methods to define additional query constraints on your `has` queries,
> such as inspecting the content of a comment:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

// Retrieve posts with at least one comment containing words like code%...
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'code%');
})->get();

// Retrieve posts with at least ten comments containing words like code%...
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'code%');
}, '>=', 10)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see the related models in the relations array attribute

```
$school= App\Models\School::with('User', 'State')->get();
```